# while executing a py file encountering an error at module importing

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, gams-math

Please help me on this, getting the following error,

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "abdm.py", line 9, in 
>   from core.api import rest_api
>   File "D:\Mydev\Development\abdm\core\api.py", line 3, in 
>   from core import data, tasks

here are the code and the directory path

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO  
from core.api import rest_api
from core.signals import task_added, task_completed,
worker_before_execution, worker_after_execution, task_deleted
from core.commands import command_manager
import settings
```

Directory path:

- abdm

  - Core

    - **init**.py
    - api.py
  - abdm.py

I'm using Python 3.5. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the stracktrace:

```
Exception in user code:
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "abdm.py", line 10, in <module>
        from core.api import rest_api
      File "D:\abdm\Development\abdm\core\api.py", line 3, in <module>
        from core import data, tasks
      File "D:\abdm\Development\abdm\core\tasks.py", line 14, in <module>
        from gams import *
      File "D:\Installation\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\gams\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .workspace import *
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    D:\Installation\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask\exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.script is deprecated, use fla
    sk_script instead.
      .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "abdm.py", line 18, in <module>
        from core.commands import command_manager
      File "D:\abdm\Development\abdm\core\commands.py", line 5, in <module>
        from core.tasks import GamsWorker, ResultCollector
      File "D:\abdm\Development\abdm\core\tasks.py", line 14, in <module>
        from gams import *
      File "D:\Installation\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\gams\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .workspace import *
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace if you can

Comment: You seem to have failed to quote the actual error.

Comment: That is the actual error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "abdm.py", line 9, in from core.api import rest_api File "D:\Mydev\Development\abdm\core\api.py", line 3, in from core import data, tasks

Comment: @Raskayu added the stacktrace

Comment: It failed because dind't found something in the gams directory, maybe you need to check this https://www.gams.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fgams.doc%2Fapis%2Fpython%2F_p_y__t_u_t_o_r_i_a_l.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue is GAMS doesn't support Python 3.5.

Thanks for your help guys.